# Notepad++ удалить все до и после определенного слова

Tags: notepad++

Есть более 5000 строк где мне нужно удалить разные ID (в столбце это цифры) и мена картинок с расширением gif

Требуется именно удалить **ВСЕ** после слова "body" и до слова "gif"
Затем я эти "body" и "gif" удалю.

```
body .post-38644{  images/116f39ym02.gif
body .post-38647{  images/4vtkls6qwtr.gif
body .post-38650{  images/148mip4xf7.gif
body .post-38656{  images/148mip4xf7.gif
body .post-38659{  images/11ltt7n27ba.gif
body .post-38662{  images/11ltt7n27ba.gif
```

Какое регулярное выражение применить в notepad++ чтобы удалить **ВСЕ** после слова "body" и до слова "gif"  Заменить на пусто.

Comment: Поискать по маске `^body(.*)gif$` и заменить на что нужно?

Comment: Почему не удалить сразу, за один раз?